# How to say "I guess timezone is a huge/colossal obstacle" in a better way?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'd like to express that sometimes it's really hard to communicate when there is a difference of 12 hours between two countries but I wanted to say that you have to blame timezone for that. I don't want to use several sentences to express the phrase. Just one.

Comment: I don't get it. What is it you think is wrong with saying that "Working in different time zones is a huge obstacle"?

Comment: I would just go for **big**. Huge and colossal are overkill. I agree with joiedevivre that replacing "I guess" with "Working in different time zones" is an improvement: if the communication isn't work related, you could say "Living in...".

Comment: @JavaLatte Oh, for some reason, I think I thought the OP was only asking about using huge or colossal. Must have been the slash. Certainly, *big* is probably better, unless there's evidence to support *huge* or *colossal*. Perhaps, no adjective works best of all: *Working in different time zones is an obstacle to communication.*

Comment: @joiedevivre I'm not a native speaker so when Grammarly highlights something I trust it as the best friend's advice. I thought the whole sentence sounds just weird. I googled it and 'no results,' so I thought there was something wrong with this sentence. You proved my point by having rephrased my sentence to: "Working in different time zones is a huge obstacle."

Comment: @Codewife_101 The fault interpreting your question was all mine, and I'm very glad if you found my rephrasing useful, anyway!

Comment: @joiedevivre Is it possible to say something like that: "What can I say, working in different time zones is an obstacle to communication." Using your phrase without any introduction ("what can I say" in that case) sounds to me little out of context, especially in writing. Am I right?

Comment: @Codewife_101 It's a little bit informal, and it does need context. But it would work in the right context: *I know we're behind schedule, but what can I say? Working in different time zones is an obstacle to communication.* Note, however, that it also sounds like you are refusing to accept any responsibility and like you could possibly be taking the situation too lightly. Leaving it out and just saying something like *I know we're behind schedule (or whatever the problem is), but working in different time zones is an obstacle to communication,* might be better.

Comment: @joiedevivre If I were you, I would use an answer instead of a comment. You gave me the best answer, and I wanted to vote for it. I would also add "rephrasing" or "rephrase" tag to my question, but unfortunately my reputation is too low to do that.

Comment: @Codewife_101 Unfortunately, I was too dimwitted to come up with this answer on my own without the exchange in the comments. I'm just glad it was helpful!

Comment: @JavaLatte, you both, figured out the best answer to my question. Thanks a lot! (probably I shouldn't write any thanks here, but I wanted to stress it somehow.)

Answer (score 1):

***The time difference ...***

- is a problem
- is the bane of [my|our] existence
- is a real bugbear
- makes it hard to communicate in real time
- means there is a very small window of time for overlapping communications
- makes it hard to keep in touch
- makes it difficult to keep up to date without scheduling calls outside normal working hours
- [Philosophical: You know, it's not the size of a zone that's important, it's what's in it that matters.](https://www.elyricsworld.com/roxanne_-_20_elongated_nose_joke_insults_lyrics_steve_martin.html)

***The time difference ...***

- isn't that big a deal; it's the same when people work different shifts
- doesn't hurt, we exchange most of our information by email
- means we can cover for each other when customers are far away from our own time zone
- [Chronographic: Finally, an IT department that can satisfy two sets of core business hours at once!](https://www.elyricsworld.com/roxanne_-_20_elongated_nose_joke_insults_lyrics_steve_martin.html)